# In IE11, XML DOM node is broken down into multiple children based on white-space

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, internet-explorer-11, xmldom

The existing code mades an ajax call to the server. On success it does something like this:

```
var result = transport.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('contents')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
...process the result
```

Previously this was working fine in Chrome and FF (and I thought versions of IE as well), but I just realized that in IE11 there is some strange behavior happening where `firstChild.nodeValue` only contains the expected content up to certain line break/white space characters.

So the result of `firstChild.nodeValue` is only `<!DOCTYPE HTML ><!`. and instead of one child node, there are now many of them, and this only seems to happen in IE.

In Chrome developer tools, when I put a breakpoint on the success call, the result of `transport.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('contents')[0]` looks like:

```
<contents>
    <![CDATA[ <!DOCTYPE HTML ><!-- a comment -->
        ...actual expected content here.
    ]]>
</contents>
```

However in IE11 developer tools it looks like:

```
<contents>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML ><!
-- 
a comment 
--
>
...actual expected content here.
<contents>
```

Am I doing something wrong when processing what is returned on success? Is there a better way to retrieve the content I am looking for in a way that is compatible with both IE and 'the rest'?

Comment: Given the snippet of XML you have shown that `contents` element should have three child nodes, a text node with white space, a CDATA section node followed by a text node with white space. I don't see why there should be a single child node. If you want the contents of an element node as a string why don't you use `textContent` (maybe backed up by `text` for old IE/MSXML)?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem in http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/javascript/2015/test2015080802.html and when tested with IE 11, Firefox 39 and Chrome 44 on Windows 8.1 I get the same result, three child nodes.